# How to iterate and take all values using beautiful soup to scrape website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's a part of my HTML page that I parse into variable using Beautiful Soup. I need to extract some of the text values and insert them into table later on.
I need the name of the player, team and points.

I can get the first player name, and the second one using next_sibling but couldn't iterate through the whole page.

```
<h3>NBA Player Points</h3>
<br>

0089, Thu Jan 16 03:00:00 CET 2020, DEN/CHA-Murray J. (DEN)
<ul>
<li>Player Points  [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.85, Over : 1.85, OU : 18.5]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Index Rating [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Assists [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Rebounds [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
</ul>

0761, Thu Jan 16 03:00:00 CET 2020, DEN/CHA-Rozier T. (CHA)
<ul>
<li>Player Points  [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.75, Over : 1.95, OU : 18.5]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Index Rating [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Assists [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Rebounds [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
</ul>

1491, Thu Jan 16 03:00:00 CET 2020, DEN/CHA-Grant J. (DEN)
<ul>
<li>Player Points  [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.85, Over : 1.85, OU : 13.5]</li>
<li>Player Points [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Index Rating [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Assists [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
<li>Player Rebounds [Under : 1.0, Over : 1.0, OU : 0.0]</li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I'd like to get from this HTML:

**Player:** Murray J.

**Team:** DEN

**Player Points:** 18.5

**Player:** Rozier T.

**Team:** CHA

**Player Points:** 18.5

**Player:** Grant J.

**Team:** DEN

**Player Points:** 13.5

Any ideas?

Comment: what's url? there might be an API that could get you the data easier from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant code, but it should get you there. The main string manipulation tool used here is the `partition()` method which splits a string into 3 sub-strings around a separator. From these are then stripped off unnecessary characters using the `strip()` and `replace()` methods.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
players = """[your html above]"""

soup = bs(players,'lxml')
names = soup.select('ul')
for name in names:
    dat = name.previous.strip().partition('-')[2]
    print('Name:',dat.partition('. ')[0]+'.')
    print('Team:',dat.partition('. ')[2].replace('(','').replace(')',''))
    print('Player Points:',name.select('li')[2].text.partition(', OU : ')[2].replace(']',''))
```

Output:

```
Name: Murray J.
Team: DEN
Player Points: 18.5
Name: Rozier T.
Team: CHA
Player Points: 18.5
Name: Grant J.
Team: DEN
Player Points: 13.5
```

Comment: This will partly work, I parse the html page from url using requests, therefore I don't know the exact number of the players. Will need to find a better way to iterate through items list maybe, then with len get the number of players. Thank you anyways!